# Showing equivalences for a open set $G \subseteq \mathbb{C}$

Tags: general-topology

> Let $G \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ be open. Then show that the following
> statements are equivalent:
>
> i) $G$ is path-connected.
>
> ii) If $G = G_1 \cup G_2$ for $G_1$, $G_2$ open in $\mathbb{C}$ and $G_1 \cap G_2 = \varnothing$, then $G_1 = G$ or $G_2 = G$.
>
> iii) If $G_1 \subseteq G$ is open and relatively closed in $G$, then $G_1 = G$ or $G_1 = \varnothing$.

I have already shown that ii) and iii) are equivalent. It would be nice to get a hint, which equivalences I should show next. I thought of showing i) is equivalent to ii) but somehow I do not see how the proof should work. Also I considered i) implies ii) implies iii) implies i) as usual, but I am also stucked a  bit there.

Comment: (i) implies (ii) is easy.

Comment: For (ii) implies (i), see https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Connected_Open_Subset_of_Euclidean_Space_is_Path-Connected

Comment: A hint on why (i) implies (ii): consider a path $\phi$ in $G$ connecting a point in $G\cap G_1$ to a point in $G\cap G_2$. What can you say about the sets $\phi^{-1}(G_1)$ and $\phi^{-1}(G_2)$, which are subsets of $[0,1]$?

Comment: A hint on why (iii) implies (i). Choose an arbitrary point $x \in G$ and let $G_1 = \{y \in G \mid y$ is path connected to $x\}$

Comment: @PaulSinclair Thanks a lot, this saved me alot of work! We have that $$[a,b] = \gamma^{-1}(G \cap G_1) \cup \gamma^{-1}(G \cap G_2)$$ where the union is disjoint and both sets are open, hence they disconnect $[a,b]$ which is a contradiction to the connectedness of $[a,b]$.

Comment: Exactly. Do you also understand the second hint?

Comment: @PaulSinclair Yes, thanks a lot!